# How to get text of an element containing rupee symbol in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, unicode, selenium-webdriver

Html element
`<div id="id">₹120</div>`

`driver.findElement(By.id("id")).getText();` returns ? 120

I am trying to get this element text in string, but it returns ? instead of ₹

Comment: How are you testing this value? Console, Text, Webpage?

Comment: This value is on Webpage and I am fetching it to display on console

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: Windows 8.1 @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: The Windows console does not properly support Unicode characters. You should write the output to a file instead.

Comment: I wrote output to file and this is the output â‚¹

Comment: What encoding did you use to write the file and what tool did you use to read the file?

Comment: Utf 8 encoding to write the file and read file in eclipse text editor

Comment: Does Eclipse know it's a UTF-8 encoded file? You're best off opening it in Notepad++ and ensure the encoding is set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse please do this:
Go to Run Configurations and make sure console-encoding is UTF-8

[image]